# How can I write a document db query which returns results of sub-documents satisifying any conditions of input list?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Let's assume that I have the following document:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "obj1",
    "field": [ "Foo1", "Foo3" ]
  },
  {
    "name": "obj2",
    "field": [ "Foo2" ]
  },
  {
    "name": "obj3",
    "field": [ "Foo3" ]
  },
  {
    "name": "obj4",
    "field": [ "Foo1" ]
  }
]
```

I want to write a query which returns obj1, obj3, and obj4 when field = "Foo1" or "Foo3" are searched for. Obviously I can write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.field, "Foo1") OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.field, "Foo3")
```

Though I want to avoid constructing a long query by concatenating query string with ARRAY_CONTAINS for each value in search list.

How can this query be expressed succinctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite the query using `JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT c
FROM c
JOIN tag IN c.field
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(["Foo1", "Foo3"], tag)
```

Note that if you have an object with both tags, then it would occur multiple times in the result, and you have to perform distinct/de-duping on the client side.